# Tradução de "draft" no contexto militar

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Eu me lembro muito de que existe uma palavra muito específica na língua portuguesa que designa "recrutamento involuntário", quando o exército obriga a população civil a ir para a guerra ("draft" em inglês). Não estou pensando numa palavra como 'alistamento' ou 'recrutamento', mas uma palavra específica para essa situação.

Comment: Mas o recrutamento não pode ser involuntário? Quando o serviço militar era obrigatório em Portugal, os soldados eram recrutas; ia-se à recruta; etc. Não é assim?

Comment: talvez seja a palavra mobilização ?

Answer (score 5):

Acredito que podemos usar a palavra **Conscrição**

trecho da wikipedia:

> Conscrição (do latim conscriptione) é um termo geral para qualquer
>   trabalho involuntário requerido por uma autoridade estabelecida. É
>   mais frequentemente, contudo, associado ao serviço militar
>   obrigatório.

Fonte: [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscri%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Comment: Sim porque draft é conscript. :)

Answer (score 4):

Em pt-BR temos um **verbo** para a ação de recrutamento involuntário: **convocar**.

No Brasil, em caso de guerra, todos os homens com idade compreendida entre 18 e 55 anos são **convocados** pelas Forças Armadas (exército, marinha e aeronáutica)

> [**convocar**](https://www.dicio.com.br/convocar/) *verbo transitivo* - "chamar (alguém) para prestar serviço militar" - "O exército convocou os oficiais da reserva."
>
> [**definição 4 do Priberam**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/convocar) - 4. Solicitar imperativamente para prestar determinado serviço (ex.: convocar para o serviço militar; o treinador ainda não decidiu se vai convocar o jogador)

O substantivo correspondente é "convocação"

Comment: Convocar também é o verbo utilizado pela justiça eleitoral brasileira quando seleciona cidadãos para trabalharem nas eleições (como mesários, fiscais, etc). A carta enviada às pessoas selecionadas tem um título como "Carta convocatória" e no texto há algo como "você foi convocado". Este caso é semelhante ao do exército, pois as pessoas selecionadas têm o dever de trabalhar durante as eleições e [é preciso pedir dispensa à justiça caso não desejem servir à convocação](http://www.tse.jus.br/eleitor/mesario/perguntas-frequentes-canal-do-mesario#pergunta-3)